# array intersection in multidimensional array using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays $firstarray and $secondarray as below:

```
[$firstarray = 0] => Array (
[id] => 1.25
[Name] => rose
[Number] => 15
[DOB] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [Day] => 13
        [Month] => 5
        [Year] => 1993
        )
    )
[SSN] => Array (
    [0] => 12345
    [1] => 3455
    )
)
[1] => Array (
  [id] => 1.15
  [Name] => orchid
  [Number] => 7
  [DOB] => Array (
     [0] => Array (
        [Day] => 3
        [month] => 7
        [Year] => 1912
        )
     )
 [SSN] => Array (
     [0] => 12365
     [1] => 3465
     )
 )





 $secondarray = Array ( [Day] => 13 [Month] => 5 [Year] => 1993 )
```

i want to loop through mfirstarray and then array intersect with each item in firstarray with second array .

```
  foreach ( $firstarray as $item ) {

      print_r(array_intersect_assoc( $secondarray, $item ); 
  }
```

what my problem is the two arrays should intersect only in first iteration,but my code intersecting in all iterations. i think it only intersecting keys i.e  day,month,year. how can i check whether values are also matched.van someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for

```
$result = array();
foreach ( $firstarray as $item ) {
    $instersectArray=array_intersect_assoc($secondarray,$item['DOB'][0]);
    if($instersectArray){
        $result[] = $item;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Check [Demo](https://3v4l.org/4FP4b)

If you need only one match

```
$result = array();
foreach ( $firstarray as $item ) {
    $instersectArray=array_intersect_assoc($secondarray,$item['DOB'][0]);
    if($instersectArray && empty($result)){
        $result[] = $item;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Check [Demo](https://3v4l.org/O2Alk)